# Recorrer y obtener valores de Json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Estoy trayendo un json a través de una llamada , al recorrerlo solo puedo acceder a la primer llave y los valores del objeto, cuando inicio el mismo procedimiento con las demás llaves no obtengo resultados. Que estoy haciendo mal?

```js
$.getJSON("http://www.elheraldo.com.ar/2019/cron/horoscopo.php", function(data) {

  $.each(data, function(index, element) {

    $.each(element, function(i, e) {

      console.log(e);

    })

  })
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Este sería el ejemplo de la primer llave y sus valores a la que puedo acceder.

```js
$.getJSON("http://www.elheraldo.com.ar/2019/cron/horoscopo.php", function(data) {

  $.each(data, function(index, element) {

    $.each(element["Aries"], function(i, e) {

      console.log(e["fecha"]);

    })

  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: un array y un objeto son cosas diferentes y no se iteran del mismo modo, por otro lado ¿cuál es el resultado qué esperas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es iterar cada horóscopo intenta esto.

```
$.each(data, function(index, element) {

    $.each(element, function(index, horoscopoData) {

      const horoscopoNombre = Object.keys(element)[0];
      console.log("Nombre del horoscopo: " + horoscopoNombre);
      console.log(horoscopoData);
      console.log("Fecha: " + horoscopoData.fecha);
    })
  })
```

Comment: Genial! y cual seria el modo de iterar alguno en particular?

Comment: $.each(data, function(index, element) {
    // Aqui tienes el horoscopo por cada vuelta.
    const horoscopos = Object.keys(element)[0];
    if (horoscopos == "Cáncer") {
      
      $.each(element, function(index, horoscopoData) {
        console.log(horoscopoData);
        console.log("Fecha: " + horoscopoData.fecha);
        console.log("amor: " + horoscopoData.amor);
      })
    }

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que `data` sí es un arreglo, pero cada elemento dentro de `data` es un objeto no un arreglo por eso no funciona al iterar. Puedes corregirlo  así:

```
$.each(data, function(index, element) {

    console.log(element.fecha);
  })
```